# adding image next to the <title> not on address bar

Tags: html, title

I am trying to add image next to my title, so not on address bar and I am using this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/title-icon.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
```

it doesnt work at all. I already made some research and and I couldnt find anything useful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Already checked it out. I wasnt sure if it does what I want. will it also add the image to the tile??

Comment: Depends on browser, and use `.ico`

Comment: And name the file favicon.ico.

Comment: Did you make icon file by converting it or just changed the name?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a 16x16 png and use `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>`
where favicon.png is your icon.Actually, to make your favicon work in all browsers, you must have more than 10 images in the correct sizes and formats.
Most browswers will pick up favicon.ico from the root directory of the site without needing to be told; but they don't always update it with a new one right away.

However, I usually go for this:

`<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />`